# Apply coupon in create order by programming magento

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, coupon

I am successful able to create order by programming but unable to apply coupon in that order.

```
{




$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId());

if ('do customer orders') {
        // for customer orders:
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                ->setWebsiteId(1)
                ->loadByEmail('customer@example.com');
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer);
} else {
        // for guesr orders only:
        $quote->setCustomerEmail('customer@example.com');
}

// add product(s)
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(8);
$buyInfo = array(
        'qty' => 1,
        'voucher'=>'Testcode',
        // custom option id => value id
        // or
        // configurable attribute id => value id
);
$quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($buyInfo));

$addressData = array(
        'firstname' => 'Test',
        'lastname' => 'Test',
        'street' => 'Sample Street 10',
        'city' => 'Somewhere',
        'postcode' => '123456',
        'telephone' => '123456',
        'country_id' => 'US',
        'region_id' => 12, // id from directory_country_region table
);

$billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($addressData);
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($addressData);

$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()
                ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
                ->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');


// For coupon applied on this order             

//$quote->setCouponCode('test')->setDiscountAmount('10')->setBaseDiscountAmount('10')->setDiscountDescription('your-discount-description');





$quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'checkmo'));





$quote->collectTotals()->save();

$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
$service->submitAll();
$order = $service->getOrder();

printf("Created order %s\n", $order->getIncrementId());
}
```

Kindly let me know how to apply the coupon code with above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once quote is created follow below, this may resolve your issue.

```
$quote_obj = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quote_id); // QUOTE ID IS YOUR CURRENT QUOTE ID


$quote_obj->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
$quote_obj->setCouponCode($coupon_code)->save();
$quote_obj->collectTotals()
          ->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `\Mage_Checkout_CartController::couponPostAction`

If you are not interested in validation etc, then **all you have to do is**:

```
$quote->setCouponCode($couponCode);
```

That should be it since you are calling `$quote->collectTotals()->save();` later

Comment: Hi, With this code $quote->setCouponCode($couponCode); I am able the coupon in my quote table but this is not working with total as i am using  $quote->collectTotals()->save(); for save the amount .Please give me suggestion